# NuGet release.config.install.xdt Retain Transforms

Tags: transform, nuget, xdt-transform, xdt

I'm creating a NuGet package that contains a *web.release.config.install.xdt* file. But, every transform in the file is processed by NuGet.

Here's the contents of the *web.release.config.install.xdt* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!-- I only want this xdt:Transform to be handled by NuGet -->
  <solr xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <!-- the below xdt:Transform attributes are also processed by NuGet -->
    <server id="location" url="http://192.168.1.100:8983/solr/geo" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(id)" />
  </solr>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions on the proper way to escape the nested transforms so they are retained for the web.release.config file?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding an answer to this?

Comment: I have placed a [question](http://blog.nuget.org/20130920/how-to-use-nugets-xdt-feature-examples-and-facts.html) regarding this on nuget blog.